# sudo useradd wont make home directory

Tags: sql, linux, addition, home-directory

I have an automatic script which works, only it just never makes a home directory. The data is extracted from a database.

Heres the script:

```
$SQL -s -e "SELECT uid, password FROM registrations WHERE processed = 0"   \
|  while read A B; do
        sudo useradd   $A -p $B -m /home/
```

as you can see the `-m` is there, but it seems to ignore it and never make a home directory and I have no idea why. I must be missing something but i've no idea what

Comment: Exactly how are you executing the `automatic script`?

Comment: At the moment, by typing . test.sh

Comment: Does the user that you are running the script on have privileges enough to perform the `useradd`? I mean, if you run the `useradd ...` directly from the console without `sudo`, does it work? Finally, if you run the whole script using sudo `sudo ./test.sh` does it work?

Comment: yes at the moment its run as root, and creates the user but not the home directory

Comment: This command shall create a home directory when you try to su as this user. It is possible that the home directory even if it is listed in /etc/passwd will be created afer the first time you try to login as this user.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `man useradd` you'll see that the `-m` does not expect a parameter.

Running it this way should do the trick (or at least it just did on my Debian Squeeze):

```
useradd $A -p $B -m
```

In the man pages you'll also find other useful options such as: `-d` or `-b`

Comment: I did also try: useradd $A -p $B -m and it did the same

Comment: If you run it from the console `useradd zzz1 -p temp4you -m`, does it work? If not, then you must be having trouble with the values of `$A` and `$B` and you should `echo` the whole command to see what it is actully being executed there. You could also try echoing the result `echo $?` immediately after the command is executed. That would help debugging